# How to adjust timestamp timezone offset for YYYY-MM-DD''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSZ format timestamp in presto?

Tags: sql, timestamp, timezone, presto, timezone-offset

I have a dataset with timestamp strings like `'2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400'` I would like to convert it to `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'` format but adjusting for the timezone difference.

So for the above, how convert `'2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400'` to `'2022-05-25T17:31:22.566'` in Presto?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In which timezone you want the initial time data to be converted to?

Comment: Any timezone would work, I'm trying to calculate difference between two times but they are indifferent timezone - wishing to convert to same one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from_iso8601_timestamp`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) to parse date, then cast to `timestamp` to remove timezone info (will be treated as UTC, `at time zone 'UTC'` should have the same effect) and use `date_format` to get required output format:

```sql
select date_format(
        cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400') as timestamp),
        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
```

Or

```sql
select date_format(
    from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400') at time zone 'UTC', 
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-05-25T17:31:22 |

Comment: hmm looks like it's not working on my side, it simply removed the time zone without adjusting for the hours: 
`select date_format(cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400') as timestamp),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')`

output:

`2022-05-25T13:31:22`

Comment: @HaoXu what is returned by `select current_timezone()`?

Comment: @HaoXu Also try `select date_format( from_iso8601_timestamp('2022-05-25T13:31:22.566-0400') at time zone 'UTC', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')`